# Pygame can't open song on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I have a program that plays a random wav file when it is run. However, when I run the program I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pi/home/python_music/music.py", line 19, in <module>
      pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
error: Couldn't open 'Song1.wav
'
```

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import random

f = open('List.txt', 'r+')
songs = []

while True:
    x = f.readline()
    if x == '':
        break
    songs.append(x)
f.close()

while True:
    y = randint(0, len(songs))
    song = songs[y]

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    while True:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()== False:
            pygame.mixer.quit()
            break
```

and List.txt looks like this:

```
Song1.wav
Song2.wav
Song3.wav
.
.
.
Song12.wav
```

The program is run on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, using Pygame.
Why do I get this error?

Comment: It seams like `songs.append(x)` is never reached, that might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're reading the entire line of the file including the newline character. You can avoid this by instead of having

```
f = open('List.txt', 'r+')
songs = []
while True:
    x = f.readline()
    if x == '':
        break
    songs.append(x)
    f.close()
 y = randint(0, len(songs))
```

It can be replaced with

```
f = open('List.txt', 'r+')
songs = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
```

You will also reach an index out of range at some point because the max index of a list is one less than the length, meaning you need:

```
y = random.randint(0, len(songs) - 1)
```

In my code I had to put random.randint instead of randint (I don't know if it's like this for you)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your .wavs are in the same folder as your .py
2. Make sure they are called 'Song1.wav'
3. Try `if not x == '':`
4. Put `break` under `songs.append`